# WILL I LOOSE MY DATA STORED IN A DIFFERENT PARTITION TO THE ONE THAT I WILL INSTALL UBUNTU 12.04?

Tags: installation, partitioning, backup

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 in my laptop replacing my existing windows 8 PRO (am not affected by the UEFI since my laptop was a Windows 7 intial laptop). However I have several partitions in my hard disk as shown in the link below where C: is where my windows 8 is installed and D: is where my backup is, there is also a System Reserve partition. I do not want to loose any of my backup data in D: How can I install Ubuntu without loosing this data?and once I install ubuntu will I be able to access the partition D:?

[Hard disk partitions photo](http://sdrv.ms/199tCxN)

Comment: @Nathan Your question looks fine (albeit formatting).. However, those downvotes are most probably for ALL CAPS TITLE and for lack of any research effort. Next time please consider using "Sentence case" for both title and body of the post and do some googling around to see **if** this has already been answered before. Also consider [edit]ing this post for better formatting.

Comment: @Aditya "Sentance case" I like it! ;P

Answer (score 0):

Boot with the install CD and go through the first installation steps up to the "Installation Type" menu. Here you'll be offered with 3 options: a) install alongside Windows, b) replace Windows, c) "Something else"; Choose "Something else". This brings you to a new menu where you will see all your drives. Then the procedure is:

1. Click on the Windows drive (/dev/sda1) and then click "Delete"; it will then be marked as "free space".
2. Click "New" (with "free space" selected) and create a partition with about the size of your RAM (say, 4 Gb), select the type as "swap area" and locate it at the end of the current partition; click OK.
3. Click "New" again, now create a new partition using all the free space available, locate it at the beginning, select "Ext4" as file system and "/" as the mount point.
4. Click "Install Now" and proceed along with the installation.

As for drive D: Ubuntu will provide you with full access to all its files. You will recognise it in the "Something else" menu and as long as you leave it unchanged the install wont touch it.

Enjoy Ubuntu!

Comment: Should have checked if this was a duplicate first...